# How can I convert my root partition from BTRFS to EXT4?

Tags: filesystem, ext4, btrfs

Is it possible to convert btrfs to ext4 without losing data? I'm experiencing a very low speed on read/write operations on btrfs.

Answer (score 9):

I'm just going on the available tools, not experience or documentation. You might want to test this with a partition (even just an image) you don't mind losing if it all goes wrong. **Don't attempt this without taking a backup.**

`btrfs-convert` has a roll-back function to undo a conversion. I'm not sure if this works for partitions that weren't converted to `btrfs` with `btrfs-convert`.

1. Start by unmounting the filesystem. If it's essential to the system, boot into a LiveCD.
2. Install `btrfs-tools`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install btrfs-tools
   ```
3. Roll back the conversion

   ```
   sudo btrfs-convert -r /dev/sdXn
   ```

Comment: Note, that this will only work with converted filesystems and only if you haven't deleted the snapshot of the original ext3/4 filesystem.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this doesn't work for a btrfs partition not converted from other file systems. H guess I have to reinstall.

Comment: Be aware that **this will discard any changes made on the filesystem since you converted it**.  It will be restored to the contents of the ext2/3 filesystem as it was before you converted.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you cannot convert btrfs to any other filesystem.

Comment: not true if you converted ext to btrfs! you would have a snapshot to roll back the changes

Comment: so it is true: you cannot convert - but restore or roll back to the previous state.

Answer (score 1):

I did this using a system with multiboot distros (Ubuntu on ext4, Xubuntu on btrfs). Running Ubuntu, I have taken the Xubuntu btrfs home partition, and archived it using fsarchiver. I was then able to restore it, again using fsarchiver, to a different partition and specify ext4 filesystem type. That seemed to work okay.

Still in Ubuntu, I mounted the Xubuntu root partition on /mnt, and edited /mnt/@/etc/fstab to change the mount for /home to point to the new ext4 partition, changing both the UUID and the fs type, and deleting the subvolume data. I saved the file, and rebooted into Xubuntu.

There was an error in booting, and booting halted. The error was that I had another partition I wanted to mount to my ~/Documents directory which failed. I selected to manually fix the problem. It turns out that my root partition mounted okay as ext4, but when I did a list command I got

```
#ls /home
@home
```

So the original btrfs subvolume structure was still there in the ext4 filesystem. I issued the command

```
mount --bind /home/@home /home
```

I then pressed ctrl-D to continue booting, and Xubuntu continued booting and everything came up fine. I haven't done it yet, as I'm still on this initial boot, but I'm certain I could put that bind command in my fstab file. Or perhaps I could have left the subvolume info in the fstab entry, I don't know.

What I will do instead, however (this is off-topic), is take a more mature instance of a /home (ext4) partition for Xubuntu from another computer and use that instead. I've already proven that this will work.

Answer (score -1):

**The solution that works in all cases, is of course to copy everything from the root partition to a directory on another partition (assuming you have one with enough free space), reformat `/` as `ext4`, copy back. I just did that, and hit a few issues so I thought I'd write a little howto:

- Boot on a rescue USB key, mount both partitions (let's say `/mnt` for the real root partition, and `/dest` for the partition serving as a temporary destination)
- Beware that you should mount the BTRFS subvolumes too (I didn't do that, and I lost all of `/var`, `/opt`, `/root`...). The best way is probably to do the usual `chroot` dance (`mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev; mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys; mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc; chroot /mnt`) and then `mount -a -t btrfs` so that the subvolumes described in `/etc/fstab` are all mounted.
- Exit the chroot or use another TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F2), and launch the copy, like `cp -a /mnt /dest`
- Reformat the partition:
- `umount /mnt`
- `mkfs.ext4 /dev/*the_root_device*`
- `mount /dev/*the_root_device* /mnt`
- Copy back the data with `cp -a /dest/mnt/* /mnt`
  And now (in the chroot) don't forget to
- edit `/etc/fstab` to remove all subvolumes, change the filesystem type from `btrfs` to `ext4`, and update the `UUID` (see the output of `blkid`, or switch to a label like `LABEL=rootfs` after doing `tune2fs -L rootfs /dev/*the_root_device*`)
- `mkinitrd` or `dracut`, and recreate the bootloader (I use another distro so I don't have the exact command for this step on ubuntu).
  Cross fingers and reboot.
  Finally, remember to clean up the /dest copy in the temporary destination.**